# Error using @odata.nextLink from v1.0/schmeExtensions

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I perform the following GET request `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions?$top=1`. In the result I pick out the value from `@odata.nextLink`, and get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Message: {\"Errors\":[\"The continuation token specified in the request is malformed. Please re-run the query without it and iterate.\"]}\r\nActivityId: 17442e29-6212-4a65-b469-4b097e747a44, Request URI: rntbd://sn4prdddc07-docdb-1.documents.azure.com:16737/apps/3967e85b-4707-48a6-b107-5bff0707b450/services/8b5418e9-b3aa-45c3-8360-6fd93e350e2c/partitions/4a27b929-2dcd-40bf-a03f-c8cd457bb30a/replicas/131497596513412168p/",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "674524d7-dbec-4e36-a710-757b3cbfe75a",
            "date": "2017-09-13T13:42:29"
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine on other Graph resources, so do I need to process the URL, or is it a bug?

Comment: What is the value you're getting from `nextLink`?

Comment: On my mobile, but use Graph Explorer and test it.

Comment: Here's a sample: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions?$top=1&$skiptoken=%7b%22token%22%3a%22+RID%3aF7weAMEoXAA1AAAAAAAAAA%3d%3d%23RT%3a1%23TRC%3a1%23FPC%3aAgEAAAAkAD8AIAIIAIABQAABAA7AAwAAQBAM4AcAAoAwgDkCAIgiAcBBCA%3d%3d%22%2c%22range%22%3a%7b%22min%22%3a%22%22%2c%22max%22%3a%22FF%22%7d%7d`

Comment: Well that is certainly an interesting looking `skiptoken`. It looks like there is a bug, I will surface this with that team so someone can look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late response.  This is indeed a bug.  We're working on a fix for this.  We'll update the thread when this is fixed and deployed.

Hope this helps,